# A question about the tensor product $M\otimes M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be an algebra and $M,N$ two $A$-module. In general, if $M\otimes N=0$, we can not say $M=0$, or $N=0$. For example. Let $A=Z$, $M={Z}/{3Z}$, $N={Z}/{2Z}$. Then $M\otimes N =0$, but $M\neq0$, $N\neq0$.

My question is if $M\otimes M=0$, whether we can get $M=0$?

Comment: If $A$ is commutative ring with identity and $M$ is f.g., then $M\otimes M=0 \Rightarrow M=0$.

Comment: @ Eric Wofsey, yes, you are right. I have edit my question and give a new example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$M=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$